# How to update tox environments when requirements.txt files change?

Tags: python, requirements.txt, tox, pip-tools

### Question

Normally when I change the `deps` in my `tox.ini` file `tox` will notice the change and recreate the virtualenv with the new dependencies. But if I use `deps = -r requirements.txt` to read my dependencies from a `requirements.txt` file then `tox` doesn't update the virtualenv when `requirements.txt` changes. How can I automatically keep my tox virtualenvs in sync with my `requirements.txt` files?

### Details

#### tox detects changes to `deps` in `tox.ini`

When using the [`deps` setting in `tox.ini`](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#conf-deps) to list your dependencies if you change the `deps` then the next time you run a `tox` command it'll notice the change and will create the virtualenv and install the new `deps` into the new virtualenv. Here's a minimal `tox.ini` file to demonstrate what I'm talking about:

```ini
# tox.ini
[tox]
skipsdist = true

[testenv]
deps = pytest
commands = pytest --version
```

If you run `tox` in a directory containing this `tox.ini` file then `tox` will create a virtualenv in the `.tox` directory, install `pytest` into that virtualenv, and run `pytest --version` in the virtualenv. If you run `tox` again it'll reuse the existing virtualenv and just run `pytest --version` without unnecessarily reinstalling `pytest` again. If you make a change to the `deps` in `tox.ini`, for example like this:

```
diff --git a/tox.ini b/tox.ini
index 7d92601..e45a612 100644
--- a/tox.ini
+++ b/tox.ini
@@ -2,5 +2,5 @@
 skipsdist = true
 
 [testenv]
-deps = pytest
-commands = pytest --version
+deps = pylint
+commands = pylint --version
```

Then the next time I run `tox` it'll recreate the virtualenv and reinstall the dependencies before running the commands:

```
$ tox
python recreate: /tmp/tox/.tox/python
python installdeps: pylint
python installed: astroid==2.12.4,dill==0.3.5.1,isort==5.10.1,lazy-object-proxy==1.7.1,mccabe==0.7.0,platformdirs==2.5.2,pylint==2.15.0,tomli==2.0.1,tomlkit==0.11.4,wrapt==1.14.1
python run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='4045882343'
python run-test: commands[0] | pylint --version
pylint 2.15.0
astroid 2.12.4
Python 3.10.4 (main, Jun 29 2022, 12:14:53) [GCC 11.2.0]
___________________________________ summary ____________________________________
  python: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)
```

#### You can put requirements files in `deps`

You can reference [pip requirements files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/) from `tox.ini` with `-r`, for example:

```ini
# tox.ini
[tox]
skipsdist = true

[testenv]
deps = -r requirements.txt
commands = pylint --version
```

Now when you run `tox` it'll install the dependencies from `requirements.txt` into the virtualenv.

#### The problem: tox doesn't detect changes to `requirements.txt`

But there's a problem: `tox` won't notice if the `requirements.txt` file changes. Your virtualenv will still contain the dependencies from the old version of the `requirements.txt` file. `tox` only notices direct changes to the `deps` setting in `tox.ini` itself.

Ideally you wouldn't want `tox` to recreate the virtualenv from scratch when `requirements.txt` changes like it does when `tox.ini` changes: `requirements.txt` files are often quite large and reinstalling them from scratch can take a long time. Ideally `tox` would update the virtualenv in place: installing, removing, updating and downgrading packages as necessary to synchronize the virtualenv with the `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: This sounds like a bug/missing feature in tox, really.

Comment: It's not a bug--tox without plugins doesn't even try to keep track of dependencies in external files. If tox.ini changes it'll automatically recreate the virtualenv, if any other file changes you're expected to run `tox --recreate` manually. Lots of people do expect this to just work and consider it to be a missing feature. But do consider that *recreating* the virtualenv when `requirements.txt` changes (as tox does if `tox.ini` changes) probably wouldn't be ideal: it takes a long time to reinstall a large `requirements.txt` into a new virtualenv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `pip-sync` command from [`pip-tools`](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools) to keep your `tox` virtualenv synchronized with any changes to your `requirements.txt` file:

```ini
# tox.ini
[tox]
skipsdist = true

[testenv]
deps = pip-tools
commands_pre = pip-sync requirements.txt
commands = pytest --version
```

How this works:

1. We've removed the `-r requirements.txt` from the `tox.ini`'s `deps`: we're no longer using `tox` to install our `requirements.txt` file.
2. Instead, we've put `pip-tools` in the `deps`. This means `tox` will install `pip-tools` (the package that contains the `pip-sync` command) whenever it creates a new virtualenv.
3. We've added `pip-sync requirements.txt` to the [`commands_pre` setting](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#conf-commands_pre) in `tox.ini`. Now every time we run `tox` it will run `pip-sync` before running whatever is in the `commands` setting (`pytest --version` in this example). This `pip-sync` command will have no effect if the `requirements.txt` file hasn't changed, but if `requirements.txt` *has* changed then it'll update the virtualenv.

### Speeding it up with `pip-sync-faster`

There's one problem: running `pip-sync` every time you run `tox` is slow, even when the `requirements.txt` file hasn't changed and the virtualenv doesn't need to be updated. On my machine using a large `requirements.txt` file from a real app it takes about 1.5s to run a simple command like `pytest --version` in `tox`. For comparison a simple `tox.ini` file that doesn't call `pip-sync` (and therefore doesn't update the virtualenv when `requirements.txt` changes) runs `pytest --version` in about 800ms.

[`pip-sync-faster`](https://github.com/hypothesis/pip-sync-faster) is a `pip-sync` wrapper script that can speed things up by doing a very fast check of whether `requirements.txt` has changed and only calling `pip-sync` if it has.

You need to add `pip-sync-faster` to your `requirements.txt` file, otherwise it'll uninstall itself! This is because `pip-sync-faster` calls `pip-sync` which uninstalls any package that isn't in `requirements.txt`, including `pip-sync-faster`. Here's an example pinned `requirements.txt` file containing `pip-sync-faster`, `pytest`, and their dependencies:

```
attrs==22.1.0
build==0.8.0
click==8.1.3
iniconfig==1.1.1
packaging==21.3
pep517==0.13.0
pip-sync-faster==0.0.2
pip-tools==6.8.0
pluggy==1.0.0
py==1.11.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
pytest==7.1.2
tomli==2.0.1
```

With a `requirements.txt` like this you can now use `pip-sync-faster` with a `tox.ini` file like this:

```ini
# tox.ini
[tox]
skipsdist = true

[testenv]
deps = pip-sync-faster
commands_pre = pip-sync-faster requirements.txt
commands = pytest --version
```

With my real-world `requirements.txt` running `pytest --version` in `tox` now takes about 850ms, a speed up of almost 600ms.

The `deps = -r requirements.txt` gets `tox` to install `pip-sync-faster` whenever it creates a new virtualenv, the `commands_pre = pip-sync-faster requirements.txt` then installs `requirements.txt` into the virtualenv and updates the virtualenv if `requirements.txt` changes, before running the `commands` (remember: `pip-sync-faster` needs to be in `requirements.txt` or it'll uninstall itself!)

### Speeding it up even more with `tox-faster`

[`tox-faster`](https://github.com/hypothesis/tox-faster) is a little `tox` plugin that can shave a few hundred more milliseconds off your `tox` startup time (depending on the size of your `requirements.txt` file). Just add it to the [`requires` setting](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#conf-requires) in your `tox.ini` file:

```ini
# tox.ini
[tox]
skipsdist = true
requires = tox-faster

[testenv]
deps = -r requirements.txt
commands_pre = pip-sync-faster requirements.txt
commands = pytest --version
```

With my app's `requirements.txt` file running `pytest --version` in `tox` now takes about 650ms, another `200ms` faster.

Comment: Wow! That's an interesting way to use `pip-sync` with `tox`. Thanks for sharing.